# Search for a string inside a text document

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to python and was wondering what am i missing in my code.

I want to build a class that receives 3 letter airport destination and origin, and prints out if it's in the text file

I appreciate your help !

```
class departure:
    def __init__(self, destfrom, destto):
        self.destfrom = destfrom
        self.destto = destto

    def verdest(self,dest):
            flag = 0
            destinations = ["JFK","AMS"]
            for i in destinations:
                if i == dest:
                    flag = i
            return flag
if verdest() in open('airportlist.txt').read():
    print("true")
```

Comment: How big is the file?

Comment: Show us a sample of the file.

Comment: It's 8 KB and 1114 lines. sample-                AAL
AAR
ABA
ABC
ABE
ABI
ABJ
ABQ
ABV
ABZ
ACA
ACC
ACE
ACK
ACY
ADA
ADD
ADL
AEP
AER
AES
AEX
AEY
AGA
AGB
AGC
AGP

Comment: How is the line `if verdest() in open('airportlist.txt').read()` supposed to work? First, you have to create an instance of your class, then call `verdest` with a `dest` parameter.

Comment: `if verdest() in` this makes no sense.

Comment: This isn't right: `if verdest() in open('airportlist.txt').read():`  First, `verdest` is a method of class `departure`, so you can't access it without qualifying it.  But you should really create an instance of `departure` and work with that.  Then create a loop to read through the file.

Comment: Are the codes on separate lines of the file?

Comment: Also, even if everything else works, you can not distinguish between an airport being the first item in the list, and one that does not exist. I suggest unitializing `flag` as `-1` instead of `0`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few changes you need to make. `if i == dest:` is checking if `JFK` is equal to the file contents, you probably mean `in`. Then you have a class but you never initialize it.

```
class departure:
  def __init__(self, destfrom, destto):
    self.destfrom = destfrom
    self.destto = destto

  def verdest(self,dest):
    flag = 0
    destinations = ["JFK","AMS"]
    for i in destinations:
      if i in dest: # change to in
        flag = i
    return flag
d = departure(['BWI'],['AMS'])
f = open('airportlist.txt','r')
flag = d.verdest(f.read()) #find last airport that was in file, could modify this to return list
if flag:
  print("true" + flag)
else:
  print('false')
f.close() #close the file
```

Comment: Thanks depperm! I'm trying to write just the class itself so i can call it later. Could you explain to me what changes i need to make to your code?

Comment: @Tom can you clarify what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

`read` reads the lines of a file into a single string.
If you use `readlines` instead you will get a list of lines in the file.
Then you can see if an individual code is in these lines.
Without a class, like this:

```
def verdest(self, dest):
    flag = 0 # note - not used!
    destinations = open('airportlist.txt').readlines()
    return dest in destinations


if verdest("LGW"):
   print("true")
```

If you want to store the two airport names in the class and look them up in a file later one, save the three letter codes as you do, but pass the filename contents to the checking function?

```
class departure:
    def __init__(self, destfrom, destto):
        self.destfrom = destfrom
        self.destto = destto

    def verdest(self, destinations):
        return self.destfrom in destinations and self.destto in destinations
```

Then make a class and use it:

```
places = departure("JFK","AMS") 
    #This makes your class, and remembers the variables in member variables

if places.verdest(open('airportlist.txt').readlines()):
    #In this member function call, places remembers the member variable set up above
    print("true")
```

Now, you could read the file in the `__init__` method of the class, rather than every time you want to check.

Comment: Thank you for this! I only picked up python a week ago so excuse me if i'm not explaining myself correctly. I'm not sure i fully understand what happens in your verdest example, the function will store destfrom and desto once i call the verdest function ? Also when i ran the code i get a OSError: [Errno 22], im not sure how to link the full path (although the file is in the same folder)

Comment: The class, `departure` stores the values when you make it. This instance, `places` then remembers them as member variables (in `self`) and the member functions can access them. Also, try a full filename as a raw string, if you are using Windows style backslashes. Or just copy it beside you python script.

Answer (score -1):

You are missing an argument in verdest() function call.

Comment: He is also calling a function within a class without a class instance.